# I am getting Error: ngModel:nonassign

Tags: angularjs

I am getting Error:

> ngModel:nonassign but the ngModel directive is bound using assignable
>   expressions.

What could be the issue?
My code looks like:

```
<input ng-model="objective.lastName">       

$scope.objective.firstName = 'Ben';      
$scope.objective.lastName = 'Smith';  }])
```

It was working at first. (this is on a html page and a javascript page)

Comment: I downvoted because [Without a Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example, it is hard to know what is wrong](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nomcve/)

Comment: assign input type to text

Answer (score 0):

```
<input ng-model="lastName"> 
{{ lastName }}
<span ng-bind="lastName">  </span>
```

$scope.firstName = 'Ben';
$scope.lastName = 'Smith';  }])